# Jquery Menu - Submenu toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to toggle a submenu from a menu link, this is my markup:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li id="artworks"><a href="#">ARTWORK</a></li>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <img src="../img/submenu.png" alt="submenu" width="62" height="1" />
        <li><a href="#">Sweet Life</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pleasure</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bienal de la habana</a></li>
        <img src="../img/submenu.png" alt="submenu" width="62" height="1" />
    </ul>
<li id="prensa_nav"><a href="prensa.html">PRENSA</a></li>
<li id="contacto_nav"><a href="contacto.html">CONTACTO</a></li>
```

and this is my script:

```
$(function () {

var $submenu = $( '.submenu' );

$( '#artworks a' ).click( function( e ) {
    $submenu.toggle( 'fast' );
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stoppropagation();
} );
});​
```

I don't know why, but it's not working, it should be pretty simple but it doesn;t work, I have tried everything, please help

Comment: it also give me this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on the line of the last " }); "

Answer (score 3):

You're `$submenu` variable is out of scope when you trigger the click event.
You've mistyped `stopPropagation`.
You're markup is missing a closing `<ul>`.

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/tebCS/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Fix your invalid HTML. Move the `submenu` UL to be a child of the `#artworks` list-item.